# Reading ppm files and using fscanf()

Tags: c, ppm

I'm trying to parse through a ppm file, but first need to verify if the header info is correct. A ppm file may have the following formats:

`P3

100 100

255

data...`

or

`p3

100 100

255

data...`

I'm using `fscanf (file_stream, "P3 %d %d %d", &width, &height, &max_colour);` to verify the header info. What I'd like to know is, how to move on to reading the data (`char` by `char`) after verifying the header info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the header tells you the size of the data then allocate a block of memory that is large enough and use fread() to read it in a single call - this is MUCH faster than reading a byte at a time.

```
  unsigned char *data = malloc(width*height); // or whaterver size
  fread(file_stream,width*height,1,data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `%*[\n]` to the end of your `fscanf` string to eat the last newline in the header, then you can use `fread` to read raw bytes from the remainder of the file (assuming you opened it in binary mode).

Comment: Actually, putting a `\n` in the format string will cause it to eat all consecutive whitespace that there is—if the subsequent binary data happens to begin with any of the bytes `09`, `0A`, or `20` (tab, newline, or space), then they will accidentally be consumed.  You really want to use the `%*c` format specifier, which will always eat exactly one char of input.

Comment: @Adam: Is what I changed it to now correct?  That is trying to stop at the first `\n`.  It still assumes the file is correct, though, unless you check the `scanf` result properly.

Comment: @Adam: Actually, looking at the PPM spec, arbitrary whitespace is not allowed; it's a single newline only.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason not to use the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) library?

Answer (score 0):

Using `fscanf` you can read a char with `"%c"`.

```
char ch;
while (fscanf(file_stream, "%c", &ch) == 1) {
    /* process ch */
}
```

But instead of `fscanf` you can use `fgetc()`

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file_stream)) != EOF) {
    /* process ch */
}
```

But, assuming a ppm file with ASCII encoding (P1, P2, or P3), `fscanf` is a really good option.

```
/* P3 format */
if (fscanf(file_stream, "%d%d%d", &red, &green, &blue) == 3) {
    /* RGB triplet read; process it */
}
```

**Remember to open your file in binary mode if you want to deal with binary PPMs**

```
fopen(filename, "rb");
```